# How do I replace part of the embed code with the input field of my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
   Username: <input type="text" id="username">
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="Timeout()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <embed id="avatarStudio" wmode='transparent' width='150' height='275' src='http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?a=b'></embed>
```

```
  <script>
 function Timeout() {

setTimeout(Encode(), 200);
setTimeout(Embed(),  250);
}

function Encode() {

var a = document.getElementById("username");
a.value = btoa("123456"+ btoa(document.getElementById("username").value.toLowerCase()));

}

function Embed() { 

   var url = document.getElementById("avatarStudio");
   var b = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var c = "http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?a=b"+b; 

   url.src= c.value;
   }

</script>
```

I want to replace `static.poptropica.com/charEmbed.swf?a=b` with `static.poptropica.com/charEmbed.swf?(encoded username)` for the embed link. How do I go about it?

Comment: you want http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?(encoded username) or  static.poptropica.com/charEmbed.swf?a=b(encoded username)

Comment: static.poptropica.com/charEmbed.swf?a=b(encoded username)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?(encoded username)`   then use the below function

```
 function Embed() { 

       var url = document.getElementById("avatarStudio");

         var b = document.getElementById("username").value;

        var c = "http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?"+b; 

       url.src= c;

       }
```

and looking for `http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?a=b(encoded username)` then use the below code

```
 function Embed() { 

       var url = document.getElementById("avatarStudio");

         var b = document.getElementById("username").value;

        var c = "http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?a=b"+b; 

       url.src= c;

       }
```

Comment: Actually, I figured that I would just add the whole embed code to the innerhtml of a paragraph element. Then I decided to break the string into little pieces and then concatenate them. And then between the concatenation, I added my variable. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code, i will show you my solution.

**HTML:**

```
Username: 
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="Timeout()">
<br>
<br>
<embed id="avatarStudio" wmode="transparent" width="150" height="275" src="http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?a=b"></embed>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function Timeout() {
        setTimeout(Encode, 200);
        setTimeout(Embed, 250);
    }

    function Encode() {
        var a = document.getElementById("username");
        a.value = btoa("123456" + btoa(document.getElementById("username").value.toLowerCase()));
    }

    function Embed() {
        var b = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var c = "http://static.poptropica.com/avatarstudio/charEmbed.swf?" + b;
        document.getElementById("avatarStudio").src = c;
    }
</script>
```

I hope you accept this how your solution.